# Activate Users - privilege

Tags: users

Is it possible to assign priveleges to a user group (not admin but with CP access) to manually 'Activate User's?

We have a few users who struggle with the email process but it would seem only top level admins can Activate - is that the case or is there an override?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`requireAdmin` is hard coded into the `actionActivateUser` action in line 444 of the `UsersService` file, so I suspect that there is no way to over-ride this without creating your own plugin.

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is an old post but I wrote a plugin to handle exactly this, putting this as an answer instead of a comment since OP asks if there's an override: https://github.com/billythekid/activateusers